# How can a client authorize us to collect their data from a service provider?

Tags: authorization, oauth

Our clients need to authorize our partners to release data to us. We can collect this data via a push/pull mechanism. Since our partners have never shared data before, they don't have  OAuth implemented.

What is the best way for clients to tell their service providers (our partners) to release data to us without having each partner bear the overhead of implement OAuth. Is there a standard practice for this sort of an authorization? Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want to do without OAuth? It has been developed specifically for this use case. Implementing it and offering it as a secure way for their users to allow others access to their data should be a very interesting selling point/feature as it means users won't have to proliferate their user/password all over the place.

Comment: A bit too vague - what kind of data are you talking about?

Comment: This is personal information that our partners collect. Traditionally this data hasn't been shared. Some partners don't have enough customers to justify spending resources on implementing OAuth. While I agree OAuth is the right option for this case, we have several thousand partners and it's going to take some work to convince/help each one to implement OAuth. In addition, clients don't have login credentials as they don't have to interact with our partner after they sign-up with them.

Comment: Is it a one-time data pull or will you constantly need to be retrieving information from your partners?

Comment: "standard practice for this sort of an authorization" sounds exactly like "OAuth" to me. I can't imagine anything robust that would be any harder to implement, especially since there are bound to be existing OAuth implementations you can use. I think the closest you can get to not requiring them to implement OAuth is for you to prepare a program for them to run on their machines. Whether they'd go for that I have no idea.